# How To add composite unique key to user defined table Type

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012, ddl, user-defined-types

How To add composite unique key to user defined table type like this :

```
CREATE TYPE [dbo].[jobdata] AS TABLE(
    [emp_num] [smallint] NULL,
    [job_date] [date] NULL,
    [year] [smallint] NULL,
    [job_code] [smallint] NULL,
    [order_year] [smallint] NULL,
    [order_ser] [decimal](5, 0) NULL,

)
GO
```

I want `emp_num,job_date` to be composite unique key .

Comment: `unique(emp_num, job_date)`, either in create table, or do alter table.

Comment: The fields must not allow null values.

Comment: the user defined table is already exist i want to alter it

Comment: @jarlh : Could you write the `Alter` statement in an answer please

Comment: Why downvote :( :(

Comment: You've already got a couple of ALTER TABLE answers. They do just fine.

Comment: @jarlh : these answers about tables , and i create a `user defined table`

Comment: docs clearly state "The user-defined table type definition cannot be modified after it is created."

Comment: @Aツ : ok i can drop and create but how to add composite unique key to them

Comment: just add `primary key (emp_num,job)` before `)`

Comment: @Aツ, a primary key is not allowed to contain NULL's, but unique constraints are.

Comment: @jarlh true, if op insists on nulls than it should be an unique instead of primary key.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You Can't Alter  UserDefined table types ,You need to drop and recreate again for any changes..

[From MSDN](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178136(v=sql.105).aspx)..

> User-defined types cannot be modified after they are created, because changes could invalidate data in the tables or indexes. To modify a type, you must either drop the type and then re-create it, or issue an ALTER ASSEMBLY statement by using the WITH UNCHECKED DATA clause.

Below is the way to create unique constraint on UserDefined Table Type

```
CREATE TYPE test AS TABLE 
( col1 VARCHAR(50)
, col2 INT ,
 unique (col1,col2)
);
```

**Note**:We can't name Constraints,so creating constraints like normal way is not valid..

Example below

```
 CREATE TYPE test AS TABLE 
    ( col1 VARCHAR(50)
    , col2 INT ,
    constraint test  unique (col1,col2)
    );
```

Comment: This 's user defined table

Answer (score 0):

```
ALTER TABLE jobdata ADD CONSTRAINT [Unique_emp_num_ob_date] UNIQUE (
    emp_num
    ,job_date
    )
```